# Como hago que extraiga los nombres de cada una de estas personas de un .txt usando regex siguendo secuencias

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, regex, filereader

Si tengo un .txt como este:

```
hola, soy Alexa como estas?
Hola, soy Martina como estas?
me llamo Marcos
mi nombre es Marta
Hola, mi nombre es Marta
me llamo Melisa y me gustan los juegos
me llamo Melisa como estas?
Hola, soy Melisa como estas?
```

En este caso hay  variantes del mensaje de input:

```
Hola, soy ***name*** como estas?
me llamo ***name***
me llamo ***name*** (y mas texto no importante)
mi nombre es ***name***
mi nombre es ***name*** (y mas texto no importante)
Hola, mi nombre es ***name***
```

Para esto creo que necesito una regex que identifique la secuencia previa al nombre... para mi en este caso serían:

```
Hola, soy 
me llamo
mi nombre es
Hola, mi nombre es (en este caso es la misma que la anterior deberia hacer que ignore el Hola,)
Hola, soy (aca deberia ignorar el Hola, y tomar solo el soy, asi si dijese Buenas, soy ***name*** tambien andaria)
```

Creo que deberia tener en cuenta que los espacios no importen por si dejan mas de uno.

En este caso escribieron 5 personas, pero 'Marta' spameo 2 veces y 'Melisa' spameo 3 veces.

Necesito extraer solo los nombres diferentes de ese .txt y guardarlos asi en otro .txt , de modo que queden asi

```
Alexa
Martina
Marcos
Marta
Melisa
```

Esto lo usaré para un programa de sorteo por eso necesito que quede uno debajo del otro.

Para esto estube probando con regex, pero no estoy pudiendo extraer correctamente solo los nombres espero puedan ayudarme.

De momento el code:

```py
with open('input_file.txt') as f:
    lineas = f.readlines()
    with open('name_list_file.txt','a') as e:
        for linea in lineas:
            #ACA NECESITO QUE QUITE TODO Y QUE PONGA EL NOMBRE SOLAMENTE, AUNQUE PREVIO A QUE LEA DEBERIA SER COMVENIENTE USAR UN .lower()
                e.write(linea) #y con esto lo escribo en la lista
```

Luego con este code, aca necesitaria en lugar de leerlo de la variable data leerlo desde el name_list_file.txt

```py
import random

"""
data = """
Alexa
Martina
Marcos
Marta
Melisa
"""

"""

#Creo que necesito esto:
with open('name_list_file.txt') as f:
    data = f.readlines()

data_list = data.strip().split('\n')

#En este caso seran 5 los posibles ganadores del sorteo
for i in range(5):
    r = random.choice(data_list)

    #elimina los duplicados, podria usar remove pero en ese caso solo quitaria uno, pero con lambda quita todo
    data_list = list(filter(lambda a: a != r, data_list))

    print(r)
```

Espero puedan ayudarme con eso de extraer solo los nombres del input_text.txt

Comment: Veo que trabajas con bastante texto y haces cosas pra sacra datos de estos, te recomiendo que le hechas un vistazo a la librería Scipy esta te ayudará para distintos problemas

Comment: La verdad es que no me queria meter con Scipy aun.
Pero para este tipo de cosas creo que con regex podria solo que en este caso no me esta extrayendo los nombres correctamente :(

Comment: claro que con una regex normal se puede, en un momento te doy una respuesta

Comment: @Christian Muchas gracias, la verdad casi tengo el programa terminado pero me estoy liando un poco con eso

Comment: lo siento por demorarme con la respuesta

Comment: @Christian no hay problema muchicimas gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dado que hay patrones muy obvio, que son:

- `soy <nombre>`
- `me llamo <nombre>`
- `nombre es <nombre>`

Podemos usar esto para crear una expresión regular que responda a esos patrones `soy \w+`, `llamo \w+`, `nombre es \w+`. Una ves teniendo esta expresión regular usaremos el método `findall` para obtener todas las coincidencias, nuestra expresión solo coincide con las *palabras claves* seguida de una palabra, y esta ultima palabra será el *nombre*.

```py
import re
regex = re.compile("soy \w+|llamo \w+|nombre es \w+")

with open("archivo.txt") as f:
    nombres = []
    for line in f.readlines():
        line = line.strip()
        resultado = regex.findall(line)
        if resultado: #si existen coincidencias
            #obtenemos la ultima palabra de todas las coincidencias
            nombres+= [frase.split()[-1] for frase in resultado] #agregamos a la lista el resultado de la comprensión
    print(nombres)
```

Esta expresión regular también va a coincidir con `soy una`, `soy feliz`, `me llamo ayer`. Esto es la desventaja de usar expresiones regulares y no una librería de Procesamiento de Lenguaje Natural (NLP).

Comment: @CandidMoe había pasado por alto todo eso y tampoco me centré en poner un nombre correcto a las variables, gracias. La respuesta fue editada

Answer (score 1):

Una alternativa corta:

```
patron = re.compile("(soy|llamo|nombre es) (\w+)")

with open("nombres.txt") as archivo:
    lista_nombres = sorted(list(set([hit.group(2) for hit in [patron.search(linea) for linea in archivo.readlines()] if hit])))
```

#### Análisis

Aquí empleados una doble comprensión de listas. La comprensión más interna es

```
[patron.search(linea) for linea in archivo.readlines()]
```

Lo que hace es aplicar el método `re.search` a cada línea del archivo de entrada. Si la línea cumple con el patrón, se retorna un `Match Object` que describe los items encontrados. En caso contrario, devuelve `None`.

El patrón a examinar es

```
(soy|llamo|nombre es) (\w+)
```

Cuando `re.search` reconoce el patrón en una línea, se puede usar el método `group(indice)` para extraer las partes: `group(0)` devuelve la línea original, `group(1)` devuelve el primer grupo de captura (o sea, "soy", "llamo" o "nombre es"), mientras que `group(2)` retorna el segundo grupo de captura, o sea, el nombre.

La comprensión externa recorre esta lista de resultados. Si un resultado es distinto de `None`, entonces podemos recuperar el nombre encontrado:

```
[hit.group(2) for hit in [patron.search(linea) for linea in archivo.readlines()] if hit]
```

Esto produce una lista de nombres, posiblemente duplicados. Primero aplicamos `set` para eliminar los duplicamos y luego aplicamos `list` para volver a tener una lista, a la que finalmente aplicamos `sorted` para ordenarla.

#### Demo

*nombres.txt*

```
A quien madruga dios le ayuda
hola, soy Alexa como estas?
Hola, soy Martina como estas?
me llamo Marcos
mi nombre es Marta
Hola, mi nombre es Marta
me llamo Melisa y me gustan los juegos
me llamo Melisa como estas?
Hola, soy Melisa como estas?
This is the end
```

*código*

```
import re
patron = re.compile("(soy|llamo|nombre es) (\w+)")

with open("nombres.txt") as archivo:
    lista_nombres = sorted(list(set([hit.group(2) for hit in [patron.search(linea) for linea in archivo.readlines()] if hit])))

    print(lista_nombres)
```

produce:

```
['Alexa', 'Marcos', 'Marta', 'Martina', 'Melisa']

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: muchas gracias por la ayuda